# ReactJS - Href Triggered DELETE Method

Tags: reactjs

I'm determining the correct method for triggering my `DELETE` route through the use of `href` and `node-fetch`. I had originally thought that passing a function in my stateful component as an attribute on my stateless component and then using that as the link location would trigger the function, but it doesn't appear to work and now I am left second guessing my approach. Is there a better solution to what I have attempted?

Here is my stateful component:

```
class Comment extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }

    commentInformation(e){
        //e.preventDefault();
        console.log("commentInformation function triggered");
        this.deleteComment(this.props.recordIdHash, this.recordCommentId);
    }

    deleteComment(recordId, recordCommentId){
        var body = { recordId: recordId, recordCommentId: recordCommentId };
        var route = 'http://localhost:3000/app/record/' + recordId + '/comment/' + recordCommentId;
        fetch(route, 
            { 
                method: 'DELETE', 
                body: JSON.stringify(body), 
                headers: { 
                    'X-CSRF-Token': 'csrfToken',
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            })
            .then(res => {
                return res.json();
            })  
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                this.props.updateComments(data)
                this.setState({'flash': 'success'});
            }) 
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
                this.setState({'flash': 'error'});
            });
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div className="record-comment__record">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-12">
                        <div className="record-comment__meta">
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="col-md-8 record-comment__profile">
                                    <img src={this.props.app.picture} className="profile__picture profile__picture--small"/>
                                    <p className="record-comment__info"><b>{this.props.app.fullNameSlug}</b> | <i>{this.props.createdAtDateSlug}</i></p>
                                    <DeleteComment commentUserId={this.props.app.userId} userId={this.props.currentUserId} recordId={this.props.recordIdHash} deleteComment={this.commentInformation} commentId={this.props.recordCommentId}/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="record-comment__body">
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="col-md-12">
                                    <p>{this.props.comment}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Here is my `<DeleteComment>` component which maps the comment user id to the logged in user id and if they are the same, then show the delete href:

```
const DeleteComment = props => {
    if(props.commentUserId == props.userId){
        return (
            <a href={props.deleteComment} className="record-comment__delete"> | Delete</a>
        )
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `onClick` instead of `href`.. `href` will be the same as a normal `<a/>` in a React-world

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `onClick` instead of `href`:

```
const DeleteComment = props => {
    if(props.commentUserId == props.userId){
        return (
            <a onClick={props.deleteComment} className="record-comment__delete"> | Delete</a>
        )
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Also, I think you are going to need to bind `deleteComment` method in your `Comment` component to not lose your `this` reference (see https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

```
class Comment extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
        this.deleteComment = this.deleteComment.bind(this);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In you `DeleteComment`-component you are passing a function to a `href`.. That is not correct, since `href` expects a string.

You could use `onClick` instead, and change your `href` to `href="#"` or use a `<button />`